# How do I more properly integrate an exception into my code, and future code? (C++)

Tags: c++, exception

I've recently begun programming with C++ for competitions in my school, state, etc. I've not had a lot of practice and I'm still fairly fresh to C++, and I've run into this issue with my programs where if a character is entered instead of a numerical value, the loop will run continuously without asking for input. Most recently with this program i wrote to do basic chemical conversion bars:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
class Exception : public exception
{
public:
    Exception(string m = "Exception!") : msg(m){}
    ~Exception() throw() {}
    const char* what() const throw() { return msg.c_str(); }

private:
    string msg;
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   // 'n' stands for numerator and  'd' stands for denominator
    int choice;
    float n1;
    float n2;
    float n3;
    float n4;
    float d1;
    float d2;
    float d3;
float answer;
    while (true)
        {
        cout << "Select how many conversion bars you have: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 1)
                {cout << "What is the starting number?" << endl;
                cin >> n1;
                cout << "What is the first bar (Enter Numerator then Denominator): " << endl;
                cin >> n2;
                cin >> d1;
                answer = n1 * n2 / d1;
                cout << "Answer: " << answer << endl << endl;}
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                cout << "What is the starting number?" << endl;
                cin >> n1;
                cout << "What is the first bar (Enter Numerator then Denominator): " << endl;
                cin >> n2;
                cin >> d1;
                cout << "What is the second bar (Enter Numerator then Denominator): " << endl;
                cin >> n3;
                cin >> d2;
                answer = (n1 * n2 * n3) / (d1 * d2);
                cout << "Answer: " << answer << endl << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {
                cout << "What is the starting number?" << endl;
                cin >> n1;
                cout << "What is the first bar (Enter Numerator then Denominator): " << endl;
                cin >> n2;
                cin >> d1;
                cout << "What is the second bar (Enter Numerator then Denominator): " << endl;
                cin >> n3;
                cin >> d2;
                cout << "What is the third bar (Enter Numerator then Denominator): " << endl;
                cin >> n4;
                cin >> d3;  
                answer = (n1 * n2 * n3 * n4) / (d1 * d2 * d3);
                cout << "Answer: " << answer << endl << endl;
            }
            else if ((choice /= 1) || (choice /= 2) || (choice /= 3))
                {cout << "That is not a valid option." << endl << endl;}
            try{ throw Exception();}
                catch (exception& e)                    
            {
                cout << e.what() << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
return 0;
}
```

And the headers:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <string>
```

So how would I better integrate exceptions into this code and any future code?

Comment: This is somehow a matter of taste, but in my opinion this is not a case for exceptions. Exceptions are for something that happens unexpectedly, rarely, _exceptionally_. Wrong user input happens all the time, and expectedly. It's not strictly wrong to throw an exception (albeit superfluous), but I consider it a somewhat awkward design here.

Comment: Please start initializing all of your variables when you declare them! Also, `using namespace std;` is a bad habit, and you should not do that.

Comment: 1. How would you suggest addressing the wrong user input,
2. What do you mean by "initializing" my variables? (I'm teaching myself from just messing with code)

Comment: @Damon: Right on. If the purpose of your program is to perform I/O, then I/O is not an exception.

Comment: @HM_2014 `float n1;` <- this declares `n1` as a `float`, but does not give it a value. The value is *indeterminate*. This means that any tests for comparison or value will be meaningless. If you do this by habit and then write code that may not assign a value before a comparison, you get bad results. Variables should always be initialized to a known value, often `0`.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll be sure to do that from now on. So far I've only written programs that require a value to be input before anything is executed, so I've not assigned them. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Three basic rules for exceptions (of course this is more like a personal flavor but maybe you find that useful):

1. do not use exceptions for control flow - use control flow statements for that (if, while)

   ```
   //good:
   while(isValidInput)
   {
       // check your validness 
       // e.g. if (atoi(input) != 1) ...
   }
   ```
2. do not hide already caught exceptions with own exception types (you already exactly know what is wrong - you would only hide this in upper layers)

   ```
   //bad:
   ...
   catch(std::ios_base::failure& ex)
   {
       throw myDataFormatException("Format error");
   }
   ```
3. use exceptions as low level as possible (you are wasting lots of cpu power and you can risk not realizing new errors in your program because everything is just caught in the main block)

   ```
   //bad:
   int main() { try { /* everything */ } catch(...) {} };
   // good:
   try
   {
       std::ifstream inputFileStream("~/File.txt");
   }
   catch(std::ios_base::failure&) { ... }
   ```

Comment: c# answer for a c++ question?

Comment: Could you please explain that third example you had? I've not run into those specific keywords or functions yet.

Comment: I appreciate your examples are in a different language but, in C++, never throw `new ...`. That will lead to memory leaks, unhandled exceptions, wailing, and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I was thinking at C# and not C++. I updated my answer. One the other hand I am speaking quite generally.

Comment: I disagree with 2. It can be appropriate to catch and rethrow an exception to add higher level semantic meaning.

Comment: @Oktalist Please keep in mind that I fully agree that this is matter of personal flavor. But let me ask why do you need an custom exception  class for that in contrast to an normal class or struct? Do you use it for control flow (#1)? I have had this situations quite a few times now that there is some error in the program nobody can find it because the application's log shows a complete different exception not related to the real problem anymore and in does not pop up in the debugger.

Comment: An exception class _is_ a normal class, so I'm not sure what you're asking. It's not for control flow. I admit I have never done what I'm suggesting, I'm just going by _C++ Coding Standards_ by Sutter and Alexandrescu. It depends what you mean by "real" problem; if there's an error in some data formatting, how useful is it to log `ios_base::failure`? If the data formatting is the ultimate problem, you want to include that knowledge in the exception. Note I said "add higher level meaning" not "replace original meaning". The original exception can be retained inside the higher level one.

Comment: Can you use a normal class in a `catch(NormalClass& nc)` or with `throw NormalClass` in C++? I do not think so (but I really do not know for sure). Your higher level does sth like `try { yourOp } catch (HigherLevelEx& ex) { opsWhenSthWrong }` while it could be written like `yourOp(boost::system::ec& ec) if (ec!=ec.success) {opsWhenSthWrong}`. You see I really dislike the pattern of using `throw` in a catch.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need exceptions for the particular issue you're having. What you need is to validate your inputs. You should study the documentation for std::cin and learn how to test for the success or failure of input-- see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/ and take note of failbit.

Comment: Ok, what would I do with failbit? can it be applied in an 'if' statement?

Comment: I looked into 'failbit', but I'm still having some trouble. Would I need to write a function outside of 'main()' and call it to test for 'failbit'?

Comment: You want to test that it hasn't been set after you do for example `cin >> n1`. If it's been set, then your extraction failed and you need to reprompt them. Move your code to prompt for the bars into a function (note that you're doing the exact same thing up to 3 times in a row) and in that function, try to get a number, and if that fails, reprompt.

Comment: You'll also want to test for any of the denominators being 0 or you'll be learning about divide-by-0 run time errors.